# Need help fixing my navigations code

Tags: navigation

I'm having a hard time getting our navigation to output properly.
Anyone mind helping me fix whatever I've done wrong here?

Here's how the original, untouched code look like:

```
<!-- Main Navigation -->
            <div class="contain-to-grid fixed">
                <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
                    <ul class="title-area">
                        <li class="name">
                            <h1><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i> {{ siteUrl }}</a></h1>
                        </li>
                        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
                            <a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <section class="top-bar-section">
                        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
                        <ul class="right">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Right Button Active</a></li>
                            <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Right Button Dropdown</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown">
                                        <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a>
                                            <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Right Button sub-Dropdown</a>
                                                <ul class="dropdown">
                                                    <li><a href="#">First link in sub-dropdown</a></li>
                                                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Second (Active) link in sub dropdown</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Second (Active) link in dropdown</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
<!-- /Main Navigation -->
```

And here's my attempt at solving it (with the help of an other thread in here)

```
 <!-- Main Navigation -->
            <div class="contain-to-grid fixed">
                <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
                    <ul class="title-area">
                        <li class="name">
                            <h1><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i> {{ siteUrl }}</a></h1>
                        </li>
                        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
                            <a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <section class="top-bar-section">
                        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
                        <ul class="right">

                            {# Get top-level entries in pages structure (exclude home page)  #}
                            {% set pages = craft.entries.section('pages').id('not 1').level(1) %}

                            {# Loop through top-level entries #}
                            {% for page in pages %}

                            {# Check if entry has descendants #}
                            {% if not page.hasDescendants %}

                            {# List navigation item if entry has NO child entries #}
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="{{ page.getUrl }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
                            </li>

                            {% else %}

                            {# List navigation item if entry DOES have child entries #}
                            <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="{{ page.getUrl }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown">

                                    {# Get child entries of current iteration's top-level entry #}
                                    {% set subPages = page.getChildren() %}

                                    {# Loop through those 2nd-level entries #}
                                    {% for subPage in subPages %}

                                        {# This is the place where you'd nest the next menu hierarchy !! #}

                                        {# List sub-menu navigation item #}
                                        <li><a href="{{ subPage.getUrl }}">{{ subPage.title }}</a></li>

                                    {% endfor %}

                                    </ul>
                            </li>
                            {% endif %}
                        </ul>
                    {% endfor %}

                </nav>
            </div>
<!-- /Main Navigation -->
```

**EDIT:**

```
<!-- Main Navigation -->
            <div class="contain-to-grid fixed">
                <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
                    <ul class="title-area">
                        <li class="name">
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i>
                                {% set image = entry.logo.first() %}
                                {% if image %}
                                <img src="{{ image.getUrl( logo ) }}" alt="{{ image.link }}">
                                {{ endif }}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
                            <a href="#"><span>Meny</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>


                    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
                    <section class="top-bar-section"><ul class="right">
                        {{ craft.amNav.getNav("mainMenu", {
                            id: 'navigation',
                            class: 'right',
                            classActive: 'active',
                            classChildren: 'has-dropdown',
                            classLevel2: 'dropdown',
                            classLevel3: 'dropdown',
                        }) }}
```

I ended up solving it this way instead.

Comment: http://dev.filadelfiavennesla.no looks good now! :D

Comment: Yeah, but only after going with a 3rd party plugin. Native way was way over my head unfortunately. :P

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the `<section class="top-bar-section">` tag, have a look at your inspector to see what this does. And you should better have some logic to output `active` class to just one menu item. As these are all entries of your structure, you should probably solve this with a comparison like this:

```
{% set active = entry.id == page.id ? 'class="active"' %}
```

and then add that to your list items:

```
<li {{ active }}>
```

to also make this work in your dropdowns, you should probably be save renaming the variable that holds your second level entry models in the for tag:

```
{% for page in subPages %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Carl! I ended up replacing the whole thing with a&m Nav, as that was way simpler to do.